# Скролл к открывшему списку

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка, ul, li

есть сайт berni.com.ua/ на нём реализовано то, что мне нужно. В мобильном меню при открытии li, скроллит вниз, чтоб было видно полностью открытый список.
Хочу реализовать такое же. Написал простенький код:

```
           $(document).on('click', '.menu-mobile_list li', function () {
               document.querySelector('.collapse .show ul li').scrollIntoView({
                   block: "start",
                   behavior: 'smooth' 
               });
           });
           console.log();
```

Он вроде работает, но не так как надо. Мне нужно, чтоб при нажатии на li a скроллило вниз пока не будет видно открытого только что подсписка.
Надеюсь объяснил доступно, что мне нужно.

P.S. В JS новичок

Сайт на котором я пытаюсь это сделать - http://letsshop.com.ua/

Answer (score 0):

В итоге не дождался помощи, пришлось долго гуглить. Решение получилось таковым:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-mobile_list li', function (event) {
  event.target.scrollIntoView({
    block: "start",
    behavior: 'smooth' 
  });
});
console.log();
```

Работает как мне надо -- https://jsfiddle.net/L2xpm8w5/2/
Всем спасибо)